# Find an upperbound as a function of $x$ for $|f_n|$

Tags: upper-lower-bounds, sequence-of-function

$$f_n(x)=\frac{\sin(x^n)}{x^n(1+x)}$$

I want to find an upperbound for the absolute value of $f_n(x)$ that is integrable over $[0,\infty [$

I'm stuck

Answer (score 0):

Can you think of how you might bound $|sin(x^2)|$?

What is the range of values the $sin$ function can take?

Also consider that you are working with $ x\in [0,\infty)$, using this $x$ bound on $\frac{1}{1+x}$ will give you an upper bound for that part.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that $f_n(x)$ is not defined for $x=0$, so I suspect that any bounding function may also not be defined there althought I am not sure on this.

Comment: But will this upperbound be integrable ?

Comment: @PedroAlvarès if the domain really is $[0,\infty)$ rather than $(0,\infty)$ then I do not think so no. So perhaps there is a way to bound the $f_n(x)$ with a function that is defined at zero.

Comment: So how can I use the dominated convergence theorem to prove that the integral of $f_n$ converges ?

Comment: @PedroAlvarès has $f_n(x)$ been defined for $x=0$?

Comment: No it was not defined

Comment: @PedroAlvarès so then $f_n$ could only possibly be integrable on $(0,\infty)$ so it is enough to bound it by a function integrable on $(0,\infty)$, which follwing my original answer you should be able to do